# Why attach 'm' after register in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm wondering why attach 'm' after register in ARM assembly. 
e.g:

```
msr cpsr, r0m
            ^
```

In manual, msr command is defined like this:

```
MSR{cond} psr_fields, Rm
                       ^
```

Comment: So what makes you interpret Rm in teh documentation as meaning `R0m` rather then just `R0`?  `R` means a register, the *m* is not literal; it identifies which register - 0 to 12. Had you tried it you would find that the code would not assemble - the suffix *m* is invalid, so the question makes no sense.

Comment: notice how the add syntax shows Rd, Rn, shifter operand?  Those are just r0-r15, but you need to distinguish the two registers in the instruction so when you look at the machine code above you can place the right bit pattern for that register in the instruction.

Answer (score 5):

It's not like you have to actually write "m" after the register name, R*m* is just a shorthand for R0, R1, ... R15<sup>1</sup>; in facts, [in this documentation page](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489e/Cihibbbh.html) in several instances the "m" is in italic, to show that it's just a placeholder for a number (and [in other pages](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489f/CIHFIDAJ.html) I actually saw R*n*, which is probably clearer for who like me is used to x86, where rm usually means "register or memory operand").

Your example will actually be simply

```
msr cpsr,r0
```

---

1. This in line of principle should be the idea of this typographical convention; still, in all the `msr` references I found PC (R15) is explicitly excluded in some remark, and in some models SP (R13) as well. In general R13-15 are somewhat special, and the documentation even says that R15 [is not really considered a general-purpose register](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473c/Babdfiih.html).